# Codeigniter Database inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and there is a question i want to ask about inserting information in my mysql database.I have a home.php controller, where from i can get data from my database via a model I have made, bud the opposite thing -> inserting data in my db, i can't do it. So, i have a controller function -> insertData, which calls a VIEW -> viewInserts, and in this VIEW i have a  from where I want to take the insert data and redirect it to my database. Can you help me about it. I want to make a MODEL which will trigger this action and pass it to the VIEW but am confused right now about the logic. Does the insert_batch() function will do it ?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    Very simple
    1. call view from controller 
    2. submit form
    3. save data in db or send to data in model here can add data

1. Controller  test.php

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();

       $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }
    public function add()       
    {
          $this->load->view('test');
    }
    public function save()
    {
        //write form validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name','required|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name','required|min_length[3]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            //error in validation redirect to form
            $this->add();
        }
      else {

           $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
           $lname = $this->input->post('lname');

           $insertData = array ('fname'=> $fname,
                                'lname'=>$lname );

          //save data using model function or save data directly here
          /*
          $this->load->model('test_model');  
          $this->test_model->insertRecord($insertData);
          */

          $this->db->insert('testtbl',$insertData);
          redirect(base_url().'add');     
        }
   }
}?>

2. view test.php

<form id="testFrm" name="testFrm" action="<?php base_url().?>test/save" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php set_value('fname');?>" >
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="<?php set_value('lname');?>" >
  <input type="submit" id="subBtn" name="subBtn" value="Save" >
</form>


3. Model test_model.php

<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test_Model extends CI_Model {

    function insertRecord($insertData) {
       $this->db->insert('testtbl',$insertData);
    }
}
?>
```